# bash code to add user

Tags: macos, bash

I am learning how to use bash through BBEdit through the terminal Mac 10.11.1 and basically i am having trouble adding the user and password.
Here is my code already.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creating a new user

title2="====Creating a new user===="

clear
echo "$title2"

# This will set the username for the user
echo "Enter a username" 
read "username"

# This will set the password for the user
unset password
prompt="Enter a password: "
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
    then
        break
    fi
     if [[ $char == $'\177' ]];  then # Enables the user to delete characters entered instead of making the backspace a character itself.
        prompt=$'\b \b'
        password="${password%?}"
    else
        prompt='*'    # Makes the password appear as ***** so others cant see whats being typed
        password+="$char"
    fi
done
echo ""
echo "Your account has been created!"
# Needs code to save username and password!!


# This will prompt the user to either go back to the menu or Quit 
read -r -p "Do you want to go back to the menu? [Y/N] " response
case $response in
    [yY]) 
        ./desktop/CourseworkBash/menu.sh
        ;;
    *)
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I basically need to know what the code would be where is says "#Needs code to save username and password"

Comment: Then please remove all the irrelevant crap and rephrase the question (at which point you're not having a bash problem, only a search for a suitable external command).

Comment: And maybe have a look at this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82472.

Comment: ive tried using that, but it doesnt work, as i need it to add a new user and password that has been entered before hand

Comment: And why the heck can't you substitute in the read values? You don't know parameter substitution?

Comment: I do and ive already tried that!!1

Comment: You say you tried, but you don't say what you tried, only "doesn't work". With exclamation marks. Have you read what I linked to on MCVE? What a foul attitude.